# Process name as the called executable, not the calling script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting, cron, process-management

Edit: I relalised after posting the below that the machine where this 'worked' had in fact not been restarted and the running processes had been launched using an older scheme of actual aliases (symlinks) rather than proxy scripts ‍♂️. I'll leave the question up just in case useful for anyone else.

For CLI brevity and naming dis-ambiguity I run a proxy script to call an executable binary with a prescribed arg:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/proxy.sh

#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/mydaemon -arg1 "$@"
```

(`proxy.sh` and `mydaemon` have the same owner, group  and file permissions)

Under `top` the process name is the binary, "`mydaemon`". What's strange is that on a different machine but the same OS, the script's name is used, "`proxy.sh`".

Machine where it works ("proxy.sh"):

- Arch: RPi4 aarch64
- OS:   Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS jammy
- User: user1

Machine where it dosen't work ("mydaemon"):

- Arch: AWS x64
- OS:   Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS jammy
- User: user2

NB, In both cases I am calling proxy.sh as a cron job like this:

```
@reboot sleep 10; /usr/local/bin/proxy.sh
```

Would appreciate any tips on how to figure out what is different between these environments causing this discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the machine where this 'worked' had in fact not been restarted and the running processes had been launched using an older scheme of actual aliases (symlinks) rather than proxy scripts ‍♂️. I'll leave the question up just in case useful for anyone else.